# Selecting an Item from a List based on Probabilities and Constraints

Tags: algorithm, probability

I have a list of items, and I want to randomly choose one of them. It should be more likely to choose some of these items then others in the list, so each item could have set some kind of probability.

Moreover, some of these items, or better: their probabilities, depend on different constraints. For example, list item A should have a higher probability if variable X is > 1. Or list item B should have a probability of 0 (i.e. must not be chosen) if variable Z is true.

Now, I assume the simplest approach would be to define the probability for each item and store it in a ma, or two arrays, or something like that. But is that really the best approach, are there alternatives? How would I link those constraints to the random selection and probabilities?

Comment: I'll vote to close unless you restrict the problem. There are extremely simple approaches that are fine if the list has length ~1000 and won't work at all if it''s length 10 billion.  The methods to handle the 10 billion case are quite complex, certainly not worthwhile unless necessary.  You need to say which bracket your problem lies in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "weight" each item and total up the weights. Then generate a random number between 1 and the total of the weights. Then find the item that matches that random number. Here are the steps:

**Step 1:** Calculate the points (or weight) of each and then total up all of the points.

```
    Item RunningTotal
     A        5        -- 5 points
     B        6        -- 1 point
     C        6        -- 0 points 
     D        8        -- 2 points
-------------------------------------
    TOTAL                 8 points
```

**Step 2:** Use your language's random number function to generate a random number between 1 and the total points.  Something like:

```
int match = Math.Random(1, 8); -- 8 is the total of the points.
```

**Step 3:** Find the item that matches the random number.

```
int runningTotal = 0;
int index;

for(index = 1; index < Items.Count(); index++)
{
    if(Items[index].Points == 0)
        continue;

    runningTotal += Items[index].Points;

    if(runningTotal >= match)
       break;
}

return Items[index];   // the winner
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe represent your data as a Feature tree?

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/mlbook/materials/mlbook-beamer.pdf

See slide 26.

Comment: Hmm, could you please elaborate on how I would use Feature Trees with my problem?

Comment: Each constraint is a feature/node in the tree. Your list of items are the classes. (Your dont have to learn the tree, just enter it manually).